# Angular Form Validation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I am stuck with certain scenarios in a validation. I need to valiadte a field - "First Name". Validations logic i have been using is -

- If the field is dirty then validate against regex

`ng-show="aspnetForm.FirstName.$dirty && aspnetForm.FirstName.$error.nameValidate"`

- If the field is marked required (currently keeping the field required is entirely business dependent so i am reading the true/false value from a JSON) then user may try submitting the form as it is

  `ng-show="blankSubmit && aspnetForm.FirstName.$error.required"`

where blankSubmit is just a scope variable i am setting true on submit button click.

- Now 3rd scenario is the logic i am not getting that is if the user clicks on the firstname text box and then without dirtying it, just blurs out, then the validation message should be displayed if ng-required is set true.If i just place     `ng-show="aspnetForm.FirstName.$error.required"` then on the page load itself the error message is displayed which i dont want as it gives user a bad UX.

  I solely want error message to be displayed when the attribute ng-required is set true and user blurs out of the textbox.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to create a directive which marks a field as visited which you can then check in the ng-show:

```
.directive('visited', function() {
    return{
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel){
                element.bind('blur', function(){
                    scope.$apply(function() {
                        ngModel.visited = true;
                    });
            });
        }
    };
});
```

View:

```
ng-show='form.field.$error.required && (form.field.$dirty || form.field.visited)'
```

Comment: I am actually new to angular. So if thats the best practise i will take that but is there no way other than creating a directive to do so

Comment: Not that I know of. You have a form which contains invalid fields and only want to show an error message once the field has been visited. I don't believe that angular provides a mechanism for handling such a scenario (nice if it did!).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you using `ng-messages`. Your HTML would look like this:

```
<div ng-messages="aspnetForm.FirstName.$error" role="alert">
    <div ng-message="required">Please enter a value for this field.</div>
    <div ng-message="nameValidate">This field must be a valid.</div>
    ...
</div>
```

In case you want to use required depending on some variables I would suggest you using this `<input ... required={{shouldBeRequired}}/>`. This should work, required field should be validated only when proper value is set to it.